# Deleting orders works, deleting coffees doesn't. Identical functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have to build a CRUD in nodejs+express+mongodb and I have a function to delete orders, which is successfully deleting orders by a parameter, and a copy of this function adapted to "coffees" MongoDB collection.

The second returns undefined, or simply {}.

First I modified the collection and then different sources as arguments.

Here is server.js

// This code works.

```
app.delete('/orders/:coffee_id', (req, res) => {
 db.collection('orders').findOneAndDelete({name: req.body.coffee_id}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.send(500, err)
    res.json('Order deleted')
  })
})
```

// Orders Collection. This means visiting localhost:3000/orders/Delta returns Order deleted

[image: Orders Collection. This means visiting localhost:3000/orders/Delta returns Order deleted]

// Code not working as expected:

```
app.delete('/coffees/:id', (req, res) => {
db.collection('coffees').findOneAndDelete({'name': req.body.name}, (err, result) => {
    console.log(res.body)  // returns undefined.
    if (err) return res.send(500, err)
    res.json(req.body)
  })
})
```

[image: Coffees collection. Can't delete from this table. Postman DELETE to localhost:3000/coffees/Jamaica returns {} and console.log(res.body) returns undefined]

Coffees collection. Can't delete from this table. Postman DELETE to localhost:3000/coffees/Jamaica returns {} and console.log(res.body) returns undefined

[image: postman returns {} meaning undefined]

Does anybody see something wrong? Please let me know if you require more code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally delete requests do not have a body. Why aren't you using the path parameters declared in your route? (e.g. `findOneAndDelete({_id: req.params.id}, ...`)

Comment: @JakeHolzinger I don't know but it is a good question. I tried with your code and the result remains "undefined". I have attached a Postman screenshot

Comment: Why would `res.body` be defined? You probably want to use `result`, and the response probably shouldn't be `req.body` either, that's why the response is an empty object.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger Makes sense, { lastErrorObject: { n: 0 }, value: null, ok: 1 }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had to define a ObjectId like

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID; //Include ObjectId
```

//then

```
app.delete('/coffees/:id', (req, res) => {
     db.collection('coffees').findOneAndDelete({'_id': ObjectId(req.params.id)}, (err, result) => {
        console.log(result)
        if (err) return res.send(500, err)
        res.json(result.body)
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note here.

1) Your routes are configured with path parameters, but you're trying to reference properties from `req.body`. I'm not sure how this is working in the first route, but I expect that it should not. You should be using `req.params` to access the path parameters.

```
app.delete('/orders/:coffee_id', (req, res) => {
 db.collection('orders').findOneAndDelete({name: req.params.coffee_id}, (err, result) => {
    ...
  })
})
```

2) In the second route you've declared a path parameter `id`, but you're attempting to access a property called `name`. This is where the implementation differs from the "working" route. It's not clear at face value if you want to use the `ObjectId` of document to perform deletions, or if you were planning using the `name` of the document.

Using the `ObjectId`:

```
app.delete('/coffees/:id', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('coffees').findOneAndDelete({_id: req.params.id}, (err, result) => {
    ...
  })
})
```

Using the `name`:

```
app.delete('/coffees/:name', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('coffees').findOneAndDelete({name: req.params.name}, (err, result) => {
    ...
  })
})
```

The takeaway here is that you **must** use the same value to reference the path param as the value declared in the path param.

`/coffees/:id` => `req.params.id` (not `req.params.name`)